# Will a waiting thread still eat up cpu time?

Tags: multithreading, game-engine

I'm trying to make a thread pool for a game engine and I've been considering how my system should react to third party libraries spawning their own threads.

From what I've read, it is ideal to only have one thread for each CPU you have access to. So if my third party physics update spawns four threads, it would be ideal to turn off four threads from my thread pool while it is running, then turn them back on afterwards, that way multiple threads are never contending over one CPU.

My question is about the underlying mechanics behind functionality like conditional variables. Since spawning threads is expensive, having four threads wait on a conditional variable and then notifying them when the physics is done seems like a much better option than joining four threads and re-spawning them afterwards. But if they are waiting on a variable, are the threads truly "asleep" or are they still contending for CPU resources in the background?

Comment: What language are you programming in?

Answer (score 1):

Although you did not write what platform you are programming on, in most implementations threads that are waiting consume little to no CPU resources.

They do however use some memory (to save the stack, etc.), so you should avoid spawning an excessive number of threads and trying to reuse them as much as possible, since as you noted, spawning a new thread is an expensive operation on most platforms.

Even though you did not provide a lot of information, I'm guessing that in your scenario letting the threads wait is a much better option, as a small number of threads will not use a lot of resources and possibly having to spawn new threads frequently will affect performance badly on almost all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Any good third party library should give you the option of running it's work through your thread pool, to avoid that problem in the first place.

For example here's the documentation on how you can do that with PhysX - https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/physx/Docs/TaskManager.html